# How can you make multiple active toggles for one accordion?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a product feature map I'm trying to create. I was able to get the accordions working and the toggles to trigger the accordion, but how can I set the active status on the "+" as well. I have it set up here: https://jsfiddle.net/oz45ajq1/ I'm hoping that when either the "+" button is clicked or the accordion is clicked, it will update the corresponding "+" and accordion to active. So if someone clicks on an accordion, the "+" would change and show the user where that feature is on the product.

Here is some code from my js fiddle:

```
<div class="accordion-toggle">
<div class="map-container">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/quhRUKx.jpg" width="500px">
<a id="map-marker-1" class="map-marker active" href="#" onclick='$("#acc1").click()'><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
<a id="map-marker-2" class="map-marker" href="#" onclick='$("#acc2").click()'><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
<a id="map-marker-3" class="map-marker" href="#" onclick='$("#acc3").click()'><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
<a id="map-marker-4" class="map-marker" href="#" onclick='$("#acc4").click()'><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by setting the active status of the + sign? Could you provide me with more details? Do you want to give the `class='active'` to the `<a>` tag elements?

Comment: So if you click the accordion, I want it to open and set that "+" icon to active so people can see where the feature they are reading about is on the product. Right now, I can't seem to link the two.

Comment: I'm hoping that if I click on say accordion 3, it sets map marker 3 to active as well. Right now, I have half of it working. If you click on map marker 3 it opens accordion 3, but map marker 1 stays active since that is set to be active at the start like accordion 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Change your JS code to this: This should be what you're looking for in terms of functionality. It's not the best code but it should get you what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".set > a, .fa fa-plus").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
      $(this)
        .siblings(".content")
        .slideUp(200);
      $(".set > a i")
        .removeClass("fa-minus")
        .addClass("fa-plus");
    } else {
      $(".set > a i")
        .removeClass("fa-minus")
        .addClass("fa-plus");
      $(this)
        .find("i")
        .removeClass("fa-plus")
        .addClass("fa-minus");
      $(".set > a").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $(".content").slideUp(200);
      $(this)
        .siblings(".content")
        .slideDown(200);
    }
  });
            $(document).on('click','.map-marker', function(){
      $(this).each(function(){
      $('#map-marker-1').removeClass('active');
      $('#map-marker-2').removeClass('active');
      $('#map-marker-3').removeClass('active');
      $('#map-marker-4').removeClass('active');
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
              $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
        else{
              $(this).addClass('active');
                }
            });
        });

    $(document).on('click','.set > a', function(){
      $(this).each(function(){
      var accrIdNum = $(this).attr('id').replace('acc','');
      $('.map-marker').each(function(){
      var plusSignIdNum = $(this).attr('id').replace('map-marker-','');
      if(accrIdNum === plusSignIdNum){
          $(this).addClass('active');
      }
      else{
          $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This didn't seem to change anything for me when I added it to my jsfiddle. I'm hoping that if I click on say accordion 3, it sets map marker 3 to active as well. Right now, I have half of it working. If you click on map marker 3 it opens accordion 3, but map marker 1 stays active since that is set to be active at the start like accordion 1.

Comment: @mpeterson change `'.fa-plus'` to `'.map-marker'`. That would change the corresponding map-marker class to active.

Comment: @mpeterson sorry, I also changed this line  `$(".set > a").on("click", function()` to `$(".set > a, .fa fa-plus").on("click", function()`

Comment: Also do you want map-marker 1 to remain active? Or do you want active to be removed when a user selects another accordion such as map-marker4?

Comment: Yes I'm hoping that if they click on map-marker 3 then map marker 1 would not be active. I just have it active at the start to show the user what to interact with

Comment: The main thing I'm trying to accomplish is having a user click on accordion 3 and map marker three is set as active as well as accordion 3, so the accordion opens and the map marker changes color.

Comment: @mpeterson I edited the code to see if that's what you want for at least the plus signs. I haven't looked at the corresponding accordions yet. But check to see if that functionality is kinda what you would like to have. It isn't the best code but check for functionality.

Comment: @mpeterson I edited and updated my code snippet, try that out and see if that functionality is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I've been trying to accomplish. Thank you!